# Нужна ли тут запятая перед "как"?

Tags: синтаксис, запятые, как

Все, как ты говорил. Нужна ли в этом предложении запятая перед "как"?

Answer (score 2):

Да, нужна, это две части сложного предложения. Подлежащее первой части - "все", подлежащее второй - "ты", сказуемое - "говорил". Первая часть - неполное предложение, в нем опущено сказуемое, но его можно предположить:

> Все (случилось/произошло/вышло), как ты говорил.